# Closing Forms from Dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, client-server

So basically I have a Dictionary which stores all the Forms opened for a specific Client (Identifier).When this Client disconnects I need to Close all the forms which were opened for the Client.

But when I call Close() on each form the Dictionary gets modified and I get an Exception:
"InvalidOperationException:Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

My Code:

```
foreach (var KeyValuePair in Clients[Identifier].Windows)
{
   KeyValuePair.Value.Close();
}
```

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `foreach (var KeyValuePair in Clients[Identifier].Windows.ToList())` ?

Comment: It is a Linq method. Have you included `using System.Linq;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `foreach (var KeyValuePair in Clients[Identifier].Windows.ToList())`

PS: don't forget to include `using System.Linq;`